# HTML + resize horizontally aligned images

Tags: html, css, image

Seems simply, but I can't seem to figure this out. I have two images horizontally aligned within a parent div.  Each img contains a width, min and max width, while the parent width is set to 100%. How do I scale both images down when the parent width is set to 50% via the screen width? For instance:

```
<!-- screen resized to 110px in width -->
<div style="width:100%; display:block">
  <!-- actual image width is 200px -->
  <img src="i.png" style="width:100%; min-width:100px; max-width:200px">
  <img src="i.png" style="width:100%; min-width:100px; max-width:200px">
</div>
```

This however pushes the second img down if the parent container can not fit it width-wise. Setting white-space to nowrap keeps them inline but it doesn't scale down.  Little help?

[image: images wrapping instead of scaling down and staying inline]

Comment: Try setting `display:block` and `float:left` to the images, it seems the inline "whitespace" between them in getting in your way. also set the parent `overflow:hidden`

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jplahn/4h9Vy/

Try resizing the width of the parent container (in my jsFiddle).

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
  <!-- actual image width is 200px -->
  <img class="image" src="i.png" >
  <img class="image" src="i.png" >
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    max-width: 200px;
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
}

#parent {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You gave the images the minimal width of 100px, so obviously when the div's width is less than 200px (110px in your question), the second image will drop to another line. If you want to scale it down, you should remove the `min-width: 100px` rule on the images and set their `width` to 50%, because now -- with 100% -- they will be as wide, as the parent container.

I would also suggest you one other improvement in the code. You don't need the rules `width:100%; display:block` since these are the default values for all block elements -- `div` included.

Try that: http://jsfiddle.net/TMyr9/2/